# How to Calculate a Conditional Rolling Count by Group, comparing to current row, in Using SQL

Tags: sql, duckdb

I'm trying to create query (duckdb) that generates a "Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group" column.

I created this table in excel as a prototype of what I am after:

This formula counts the number of **past/prior** rows where:

- The 'days' value (column D) is greater than 90,
- The 'group' value (column F) matches the current row's group,
- The 'Date Closed' value is less than the **current row's** 'Invoice Date'.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Invoice Date | Due Date | Date Closed | days | amount | group | Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group | Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group formula |
| 2 | 22-Oct-22 | 21-Nov-22 | 1-Mar-23 | 100 | 111 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E3,">90",G$3:G3,G3,D$3:D3,"<"&B3) |
| 3 | 24-Oct-22 | 23-Nov-22 | 3-Mar-23 | 100 | 150 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E4,">90",G$3:G4,G4,D$3:D4,"<"&B4) |
| 4 | 31-Oct-22 | 30-Nov-22 | 5-Mar-23 | 95 | 300 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E5,">90",G$3:G5,G5,D$3:D5,"<"&B5) |
| 5 | 10-Nov-22 | 10-Dec-22 | 2-Feb-23 | 54 | 180 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E6,">90",G$3:G6,G6,D$3:D6,"<"&B6) |
| 6 | 21-Nov-22 | 21-Dec-22 | 4-Feb-23 | 45 | 220 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E7,">90",G$3:G7,G7,D$3:D7,"<"&B7) |
| 7 | 4-Dec-22 | 3-Jan-23 | 4-Jan-23 | 1 | 210 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E8,">90",G$3:G8,G8,D$3:D8,"<"&B8) |
| 8 | 19-Dec-22 | 18-Jan-23 | 20-Jan-23 | 2 | 100 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E9,">90",G$3:G9,G9,D$3:D9,"<"&B9) |
| 9 | 1-Jan-23 | 31-Jan-23 | 20-Feb-23 | 20 | 200 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E10,">90",G$3:G10,G10,D$3:D10,"<"&B10) |
| 10 | 22-Jan-23 | 21-Feb-23 | 1-Jun-23 | 100 | 280 | B | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E11,">90",G$3:G11,G11,D$3:D11,"<"&B11) |
| 11 | 28-Feb-23 | 30-Mar-23 | 2-Apr-23 | 3 | 250 | A | 0 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E12,">90",G$3:G12,G12,D$3:D12,"<"&B12) |
| 12 | 14-May-23 | 13-Jun-23 | 1-Sep-23 | 80 | 21 | A | 1 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E13,">90",G$3:G13,G13,D$3:D13,"<"&B13) |
| 13 | 18-Jun-23 | 18-Jul-23 | 1-Oct-23 | 75 | 456 | A | 1 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E14,">90",G$3:G14,G14,D$3:D14,"<"&B14) |
| 14 | 2-Jul-23 | 1-Aug-23 | 1-Aug-23 | 0 | 320 | B | 3 | =COUNTIFS(E$3:E15,">90",G$3:G15,G15,D$3:D15,"<"&B15) |

The **current row** piece is the obstacle, not sure how to fit that into the query

I have tried a window function but I cannot get the query to filter out results where "Date Closed" < current row "Invoice Date" because SQL is very set oriented and doesn't really have a nice easy way of doing this. Maybe there's a self join solution or something but that's beyond my ability unfortunately. I would appreciate any help. I have an extremely slow solution python that is basically too slow to even consider using with a large amount of data so hoping an SQL solution is available.

Here's my completely not working SQL

```
SELECT 
  "Invoice Date",
  "Due Date",
  "Date Closed",
  "days",
  "amount",
  "group",
  SUM(CASE WHEN days > 90 AND "Date Closed" < "Invoice Date" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY "group" ORDER BY "Invoice Date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
    AS "Rolling Count Very Late (> 90 days) by group"
FROM 
  main.example_tbl 
ORDER BY 
   "Invoice Date";
```

Comment: first make a column where you only have the case when and don't order it. then you see the vquery makes that what you want

Comment: At this point I am creating a 'snapshot' file, currently being churned out, which will be parquet file with a daily snapshot of all invoices and their state. I can then use the snapshot date column to filter on and the cumulative count part is straightforward. The downside is that this file is going to be humungous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use a self join.

#### Sample data using Python API

```py
import duckdb
import io

db = duckdb.read_csv(io.BytesIO(b"""
Invoice Date|Due Date|Date Closed|days|amount|group
22-Oct-22|21-Nov-22|1-Mar-23|100|111|B
24-Oct-22|23-Nov-22|3-Mar-23|100|150|B
31-Oct-22|30-Nov-22|5-Mar-23|95|300|A
10-Nov-22|10-Dec-22|2-Feb-23|54|180|A
21-Nov-22|21-Dec-22|4-Feb-23|45|220|B
4-Dec-22|3-Jan-23|4-Jan-23|1|210|B
19-Dec-22|18-Jan-23|20-Jan-23|2|100|A
1-Jan-23|31-Jan-23|20-Feb-23|20|200|B
22-Jan-23|21-Feb-23|1-Jun-23|100|280|B
28-Feb-23|30-Mar-23|2-Apr-23|3|250|A
14-May-23|13-Jun-23|1-Sep-23|80|21|A
18-Jun-23|18-Jul-23|1-Oct-23|75|456|A
2-Jul-23|1-Aug-23|1-Aug-23|0|320|B
""".strip())
)

db = db.select("""
row_number() over () row_number,
* replace( 
   strptime("Invoice Date", '%d-%b-%y') as "Invoice Date",
   strptime("Due Date",     '%d-%b-%y') as "Due Date",
   strptime("Date Closed",  '%d-%b-%y') as "Date Closed"
)
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ row_number │    Invoice Date     │      Due Date       │     Date Closed     │ days  │ amount │  group  │
│   int64    │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │ int64 │ int64  │ varchar │
├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
│          1 │ 2022-10-22 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    111 │ B       │
│          2 │ 2022-10-24 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-23 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-03 00:00:00 │   100 │    150 │ B       │
│          3 │ 2022-10-31 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │    300 │ A       │
│          4 │ 2022-11-10 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-10 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-02 00:00:00 │    54 │    180 │ A       │
│          5 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-04 00:00:00 │    45 │    220 │ B       │
│          6 │ 2022-12-04 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-04 00:00:00 │     1 │    210 │ B       │
│          7 │ 2022-12-19 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-20 00:00:00 │     2 │    100 │ A       │
│          8 │ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-31 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-20 00:00:00 │    20 │    200 │ B       │
│          9 │ 2023-01-22 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    280 │ B       │
│         10 │ 2023-02-28 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-04-02 00:00:00 │     3 │    250 │ A       │
│         11 │ 2023-05-14 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-13 00:00:00 │ 2023-09-01 00:00:00 │    80 │     21 │ A       │
│         12 │ 2023-06-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-07-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 │    75 │    456 │ A       │
│         13 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │    320 │ B       │
├────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┤
│ 13 rows                                                                                       7 columns │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

#### Self Join

We used `row_number() over () row_number` to add a row number column.

This is used as part of the join condition to match "previous rows".

```py
duckdb.sql("""
from 
   db self left join db other 
on
   self.group = other.group
   and
   self.row_number > other.row_number 
   and
   self."Invoice Date" > other."Date Closed"
   and
   other.days > 90
order by 
   self.row_number
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬───┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ row_number │    Invoice Date     │      Due Date       │     Date Closed     │ days  │ … │      Due Date       │     Date Closed     │ days  │ amount │  group  │
│   int64    │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │ int64 │   │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │ int64 │ int64  │ varchar │
├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼───┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┤
│          1 │ 2022-10-22 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 │   100 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          2 │ 2022-10-24 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-23 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-03 00:00:00 │   100 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          3 │ 2022-10-31 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          4 │ 2022-11-10 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-10 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-02 00:00:00 │    54 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          5 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-04 00:00:00 │    45 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          6 │ 2022-12-04 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-04 00:00:00 │     1 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          7 │ 2022-12-19 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-20 00:00:00 │     2 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          8 │ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-31 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-20 00:00:00 │    20 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│          9 │ 2023-01-22 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 │   100 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│         10 │ 2023-02-28 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-04-02 00:00:00 │     3 │ … │ NULL                │ NULL                │  NULL │   NULL │ NULL    │
│         11 │ 2023-05-14 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-13 00:00:00 │ 2023-09-01 00:00:00 │    80 │ … │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │    300 │ A       │
│         12 │ 2023-06-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-07-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 │    75 │ … │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │    300 │ A       │
│         13 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │ … │ 2023-02-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    280 │ B       │
│         13 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │ … │ 2022-11-23 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-03 00:00:00 │   100 │    150 │ B       │
│         13 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │ … │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    111 │ B       │
├────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴───┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┤
│ 15 rows                                                                                                                                   14 columns (10 shown) │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

We can then:

- `GROUP BY` the `row_number` column
- select the first of each LHS column (i.e. `self.*`)
- count the number of (non-null) RHS `row_number` values (`other.row_number`)

```py
duckdb.sql("""
select
   first(
      columns(self.*)
   ),
   count(other.row_number)
from 
   db self left join db other 
on
   self.group = other.group
   and
   self.row_number > other.row_number 
   and
   self."Invoice Date" > other."Date Closed"
   and
   other.days > 90
group by
   self.row_number
order by 
   self.row_number
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ row_number │    Invoice Date     │      Due Date       │     Date Closed     │ days  │ amount │  group  │ count(other.row_number) │
│   int64    │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │ int64 │ int64  │ varchar │          int64          │
├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│          1 │ 2022-10-22 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    111 │ B       │                       0 │
│          2 │ 2022-10-24 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-23 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-03 00:00:00 │   100 │    150 │ B       │                       0 │
│          3 │ 2022-10-31 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │    300 │ A       │                       0 │
│          4 │ 2022-11-10 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-10 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-02 00:00:00 │    54 │    180 │ A       │                       0 │
│          5 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-04 00:00:00 │    45 │    220 │ B       │                       0 │
│          6 │ 2022-12-04 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-04 00:00:00 │     1 │    210 │ B       │                       0 │
│          7 │ 2022-12-19 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-20 00:00:00 │     2 │    100 │ A       │                       0 │
│          8 │ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-31 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-20 00:00:00 │    20 │    200 │ B       │                       0 │
│          9 │ 2023-01-22 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    280 │ B       │                       0 │
│         10 │ 2023-02-28 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-04-02 00:00:00 │     3 │    250 │ A       │                       0 │
│         11 │ 2023-05-14 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-13 00:00:00 │ 2023-09-01 00:00:00 │    80 │     21 │ A       │                       1 │
│         12 │ 2023-06-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-07-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 │    75 │    456 │ A       │                       1 │
│         13 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │    320 │ B       │                       3 │
├────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────┤
│ 13 rows                                                                                                                 8 columns │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```